# how does pandas rolling std calculate?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a.rolling(5).std() to get a std series in a window(size=5, a is a pd.Series)

but i found the result is not what i want.

here is the example:

```
In [15]: a = [-49, -50, -50, -51, -48]

In [16]: pd.Series(a).rolling(5).std()
Out[16]: 
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4    1.140175
dtype: float64

In [17]: np.std(a)
Out[17]: 1.0198039027185568
```

I think the last element of `pd.Series(a).rolling(5).std()` should be equal with np.std(a),

but why it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to Pandas normalizing by `N - 1` instead of `N`. See the first note at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html

You can change this behavior using the degrees of freedom argument, `ddof`, e.g. `pd.Series(a).rolling(5).std(ddof=0)`.